# Problem create NotificationCompat any open app

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I have NotificationCompat sticky
it create new Notification any open app
for example if open 10 times app create 10 notification
Please help me

```
public void Notifa(){

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
  String offerChanelsName ="Shop Now Offers";
  String offerDescription ="Description Offer Names ";
  int offerChaqnelImportan = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

  NotificationChannel notificationChannel =new NotificationChannel(offerChannelId,offerChanelsName,offerChaqnelImportan);
  notificationChannel.setDescription(offerDescription);

  notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}

builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,offerChannelId);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(pending);
notificationManager.notify(notifac_id,builder.build());

}
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Updating) you can update a notification if you call  `NotificationManager.notify` with the same notification ID as before. As long as your `notifac_id` didn't change, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Tankyou  @EugenPechanec
According to documentation you can update a notification if you call NotificationManager.notify with the same notification ID as before. As long as your notifac_id didn't change, it should work. –